# Automatic (one way) sync between pandas and database?

Tags: python, pandas, nosql

I'm looking for a best practice kind of way to automatically synchronize a pandas `DataFrame` with an arbitrary NoSQL database (can be anything, I'm not bound to a specific database yet).

By synchronizing I mean automagically propagating any change made to the DataFrame to the database. Changes in the database do not have to be propagated to the DataFrame. One way will be fine. I'll initialize the DataFrame at the start of the application in order to have it sync.

Synchronization might be achieved by some sort of `onchange` hook in the pandas DataFrame if such a thing exists.

Comment: Well its not too difficult to do the sync you can write a python script and run it with a cron tab. But the problem here is this onchange part, how do you define the dataframe has change like the number of rows increased or decrease, some sort of indicator for the change to happen

Comment: Change I define as anything that happens to the data inside the DataFrame, including changes to the data structure, renaming of columns, value changes, adding and removing of rows, columns, switching indexes etc. That's why I'm also thinking of using a NoSQL database because that's way more flexible to these kind of changes than an SQL database. And the sync should happen immediately upon change, not based on a timer.

Comment: I see but based on my knowledge. The only way to trigger a write to a database is the to_sql function. Because to write every little change on the DataFrame to the database would be memory consuming,